# How to protect some data in firebase firestore?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, express, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Im trying to make chat rooms in my web app. That chat rooms will be protected by password. How to securly store that passwords?

I figure out that way:

- validation through my own api which only has access to that passwords.

I know there are firebase security rules that i can change but:

- do i have to make new collection? or do i am able to change security rules just for one field in document?
- how to make collection accesible just for api? I know that i can change in security rules that some data is only accesible for it's creator by how to make it for api?

Or is there better way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do that by using firebase functions. I created collection that matches rooms with users.

One function for:
If password passed in request is correct for room which id was also passed in request, add document to that collection that match this room with passed user id.

And another one:
Return data about all rooms which ids are connected with user id.

Code below i help it will help anyone:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true });

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.passwordCheck = functions.region("europe-central2").https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    cors(req, res, () => {
        const { uid, password, id } = req.body;

        // refs to room with given args
        const roomRef = admin.firestore()
            .collection('rooms').doc(id)

        roomRef.get().then((doc) => {
            if (doc.data().password == password) {

                // ref to room_members list in requested room
                const room_members = admin.firestore().collection('room_members');
                const is_member = room_members.where("user_uid", "==", uid).where("room_id", "==", id);

                is_member.get().then((docs) => {
                    if (docs.docs.length == 0) {
                        room_members.add({
                            user_uid: uid,
                            room_id: id,
                        }).then(() => {
                            res.status(200).end();
                        })
                    }
                }).catch(err => {
                    // user already in members
                });
                // Success status
            }
            else {
                // wrong password
                res.status(400).end();
            }

        }).catch(err => {
            // not found room
            res.status(404).end();
        });
    });
});

/* Example request for that function

curl -X POST https://europe-central2-xxx.cloudfunctions.net/passwordCheck
   -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
   -d '{"uid": "B2Xidd3Vw1PL9Kyt5ERFXCjniuF3","id":"Sjucgsyuw2723"
    "password": "xxxx"}'

*/


exports.rooms = functions.region("europe-central2").https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    cors(req, res, () => {
        const { uid } = req.body;

        // refs to rooms members list objects with given user id
        const membersRef = admin.firestore()
            .collection('room_members').where("user_uid", "==", uid);

        membersRef.get().then((doc) => {
            if (doc) {
                // get all ids of rooms that user is in
                const rooms_ids = doc.docs.map((docx) => { return docx.data().room_id });

                // get all datas from that rooms
                const roomsrefs = rooms_ids.map(id => admin.firestore().collection("rooms").doc(id));
                admin.firestore().getAll(...roomsrefs).then((rooms) => {
                    res.json(rooms.map(room =>
                        Object.assign({}, { "id": room.id }, room.data())))
                    res.status(200).end();
                })
            }
            else {
                // not found resurces
                res.json([]);
                res.status(401).end();
            }
        }).catch(err => {
            //Internal server error
            res.status(500).end();
        });

    })
});

/* Example request for that function

curl -X POST https://europe-central2-xxxx.cloudfunctions.net/rooms
   -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
   -d '{"uid": "B2Xidd3Vw1PL9Kyt5ERFXCjniuF3"}'

// */
```

Response time of the functions is like 500ms so im sure that it's not the best solution but it works :)

**It's also possible to do with firestore rules but its neccesary to have matching strucure of data.**

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I found is that you don’t have to store passwords in the Firestore, instead you can use Firebase Authentication for it.

You can create it by calling [createUserWithEmailAndPassword](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth#create_a_password-based_account), or you can also create new password-authenticated users from the Authentication section as mentioned in [Manage Users in Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users).